# Redirecting a route with a format in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I want to redirect a request to another url.

The target URL has this route:

```
get 'conversion_tracker/:website_url', controller: 'conversion_trackers',
action: 'show', website_url: /.*/, defaults: {format: :json}
```

Notice the format. It accepts a website url as a parameter. I.e. foo.com. This causes the problem in the redirect, because the route no longer knows that it should treat the `foo.com` as a single parameter. I guess it checks for `com` as a single parameter.

This is the redirect code I have right now:

```
get 'conversion_tracker/:website_url', to: redirect {|params, req|
"/api/extern/conversion_tracker/%{website_url}?access_token=#{params[:access_token]}"}
```

I then get this error:

```
bad URI(is not URI?): /api/extern/conversion_tracker/%{website_url}.html?access_token=
```

The redirect url is correct if I look at my URL in the browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/conversion_tracker/foo.com?access_token=b97b7064c4e41f226027c6cd715569d9
```

It just seems to be the issue with the format.

Thanks!

Comment: this `%{website_url}` should be `#{params[:website_url]}` i think

Comment: No difference. It still redirects to `http://localhost:3000/api/conversion_tracker/foo?access_token=b97b7064c4e41f226027c6cd715569d9` stripping the `.com` from the redirect

Comment: i was referring to the `bad URI(is not URI?)` error

Comment: adding a website-url like this is not a good idea. is there any reason why you are not passing it as a url query parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem trying to redirect images, try something like this...

```
get 'conversion_tracker/:website_url.:website_dom', 
    constraints: { website_url: /.+/, website_dom: /(com|net|org)/ },
    to: redirect {|params, req| "/api/extern/conversion_tracker/%{website_url}.%{website_dom}?access_token=#{params[:access_token]}"}
```